# I have single row should convert into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

### Please tell how to display them like

|NumberOfQuotesGenerated    |   11 
     |
TotalAmountOfQuotes                |   78100 
  |
NumberOfInvoiceGenerated  |    9 
      |
TotalAmountOfInvoice               |    8222

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try `Unpivot` syntax  like below

```
-- create table t(NumberOfQuotesGenerated int,TotalAmountOfQuotes int,NumberOfInvoiceGenerated int, TotalAmountOfInvoice int)
-- insert into t values (11, 78100, 9, 8222)

select * from 
(select * from t) s
unpivot
(
   data for 
   colname in 
      ([NumberOfQuotesGenerated],[TotalAmountOfQuotes],[NumberOfInvoiceGenerated],[TotalAmountOfInvoice])
)up
```

**[Live SQL demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/384e2b/1)**